# Toilet water supply pipe cover rusted in place

Tags: toilet, valve

[image]

This toilet valve cover is rusted in place. I can’t slide it up or down the pipe and the pipe itself doesn’t seem to be corrosion resistant. I am worried the rust if not resolved will eat into the pipe and cause a leak. Am I wrong to worry about this?

Is a fix needed or am I just worrying for no reason. If it matters I live in a cold weather northeastern state.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Likely it is galvanized steel pipe and the zinc was removed by cutting threads. So the bare steel rusted, it is primarily a cosmetic problem. Can't be sure from the photo but it is possibly chrome plated steel; same result. If you can move the decorative chrome collar and clean off most rust, some oil of grease will slow future rusting.

Comment: A spray of WD40 on the rust and left for an hour may seep into the rust and release it enough to move the cap.

Answer (score 0):

Careful probing with a chisel, or gentle tapping with same, will remove the rust. Along with a good rub with glasspaper to remove all remaining rust. Then you'll be able to lift the cowl to reveal what's going on underneath it, and replace it if necessary. Leaving it will eventually lead to a leak, but not any time soon, as the metal's usually quite thick, but a stitch in time...

Probably caused by condensation running down the pipe, so a good lick of paint, when it's dry, will slow the process down. Unless it's worse underneath, in which case,it's worth replacing.